# Prevent link wrapped in h2 from being affected by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a button test that needs to be completed in jQuery only. The site is fairly confusing, but I think I have simplified the issue below. I am trying to apply some styles to these buttons however the class is used all over and some specific instances need to be excluded.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a class="button primary" href="...">change me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ancestorClass">
        <h2>
            <a class="button primary" href="...">don't touch</a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Currently I have the following...

```
    jQuery("<style type='text/css'> 
.change-button:before
 {font-family: HPFlex2Software3ResourceIcons;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
content: \"\\e903\";
width: 10px;
top: 5px;
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
color: #01a982;
} 
.change-button-gray:before 
{
font-family: HPFlex2Software3ResourceIcons;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
content: \"\\e903\";
width: 10px;
top: 5px;
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
color: #707070;
}
</style>").appendTo("head");

    jQuery(".button.primary").addClass("change-button").css({
                   "background-color": "transparent",
                   "color": "#000000",
    }).mouseenter(function() {
                   $(this).removeClass("change-button");
                   $(this).addClass("change-button-gray");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
                   $(this).removeClass("change-button-gray");
                   $(this).addClass("change-button");
    });
```

> In previous variations of tests on this site I was able to use the
>   following to prevent specific buttons from being affected, but because
>   of how the css is being added in on this variation it no longer works
>   for me.

```
    $('.button.primary').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.ancestorClass').length === 0;})
```

> Here is the code I was using that got the error:

```
$('.button.primary').filter(function() {
   var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
   return  parent.hasClass(".ancestorClass");
.addClass("change-button").css({
               "background-color": "transparent",
               "color": "#000000",
}).mouseenter(function() {
               $(this).removeClass("change-button");
               $(this).addClass("change-button-gray");
}).mouseleave(function() {
               $(this).removeClass("change-button-gray");
               $(this).addClass("change-button");
})});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's many ways to solve your problem but I will choose your idea instead of coming with a new one. Instead of using this code :

```
  $('.button.primary').filter(function() {
return $(this).closest('.ancestorClass').length === 0;})
```

I suggest you to use this :

```
    $('.button.primary').filter(function() {
       var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
       return  parent.hasClass("ancestorClass");
    });
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h21xdbaf/) showing how it works.

An other solution would be to use the css selector `:nth-child(number)` but it's less beautiful and you have to change the selector when you add or delete elements that precede the target (with the same class).

Comment: great thanks! I apologize for my ignorance (I'm still new to jQuery) but when adding your code to my larger snippet above I keep getting token errors. Could you help me understand the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you please copy paste the error that you get from the console of your browser ?

Comment: Yes no problem it returns: VM540:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:878:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:811:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:667:21)

Comment: Ok it's not so verbal for me but anyway, can you change `.button.primary` with `div + .button.primary` to select the first button element? And thanks to that, you will no more need `filter`

Comment: I still get an error. I added the complete code above in my original question so you can see how I combined your code with mine. Thanks for all your help, this has been such a great learning resource for me!

Comment: All my pleasure, for your error that's normal : 

`$('.button.primary').filter(function() {
   var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
   return  parent.hasClass(".ancestorClass");
.`

should be replaced with :

`$('.button.primary').filter(function() {
   var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
   return  parent.hasClass(".ancestorClass");
}).`
You forgot to put `})` before the `.`